How to connect AWS DocumentDB connection string to mongoDB from microsoft azure's local-settings.json
Im using AWS to host my frontend server and use AWS DocumentDB as MongoDB service.
AWS allows the user to generate a global-bundle.pem using wget https://truststore.pki.rds.amazonaws.com/global/global-bundle.pem
to be used in this mongodb://username:password@cluster.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/?tls=true&tlscafile=global-bundle.pem&retryWrites=false&directConnection=true as my connection string to mongosh in EC2 bastion.
when it used in EC2 along with the generated file global-bundle.pem in EC2 bastion it works, but when used as values inside the local-settings.json of azure functions like this:
"MONGODB_URI": "mongodb://username:password@cluster.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/?tls=true&tlscafile=global-bundle.pem&retryWrites=false&directConnection=true"

it doesn't work.
NOTE: Im using TLS and Mongoose
